# How to make two class tags ease in separately when the page loads

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

When my page loads, I would load ".alpha" first and then a few seconds later ".omega" using jquery.  Are there any examples out there?  Would I use easeIn, fadeIn, or fadeOut?

Thank you.

How would add ".omega" to this?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {


jQuery(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".alpha").fadeOut("fast", function () {})
    }, 500)
})


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `setTimeout` and use `fadeIn`

```js
//you probably do not need to use setTimeout for .alpha, but just in case...
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alpha').fadeIn();
}, 100);

//then load .omega 2 seconds after .alpha...
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.omega').fadeIn();
}, 2100);
```

Update to answer your example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
            //load in .alpha
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".alpha").fadeIn("fast", function() {
                //alpha finished loading
                //now load omega
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(".omega").fadeIn("fast", function() {
                        //omega finished loading
                    })
                }, 2000);
            });
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).delay(2000).animate({
                    'margin-top':'60%',
                    'opacity':0},2000,function(){

                        $(this).remove();
                        if(nr==1){
                            showIntro(2);
                        }else if(nr==2){
                            $('.wrapper').fadeIn(2000);
                        }
                });
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/gVp7m/59/)

Answer (score 0):

Use callbacks in fadeIn() functions:

```
$('.first').fadeIn(function(){
    $('.second').fadeIn()
})
```

Look at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WPw25/

If you want a delay use delay() function:

```
$('.first').fadeIn(function(){
    $('.second').delay(3000).fadeIn()
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WPw25/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
    $(".alpha").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".omega")delay(1000).fadeIn();
```